# How to read unique row from excel into cucumber scenario

Tags: excel, cucumber-java, data-driven-tests

I have three scenarios in my feature file and I have three rows in excel. I want to read data from unique row of the excel when executing each of the scenario
Example : Scenario 1- Read data from Row 1 of excel
Scenario 2- Read data from Row 2 of excel

How this can be achieved?

I tried by adding a new column in excel has execute which has a value YES/NO. So the script will pick only the row which has Execute value has YES.